# Return cell from cellForRowAtIndexPath when asynchronous call present

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an issue in a view controller when it comes to returning cells for a tableview. I am using Parse backend to get a file. I have 2 asynchronous calls there. I understand that the code outside of this will execute first and code dependant on the result should be in the block.

In brief my code is as follow: I have a model array of model objects. I use the object to set the labels and the image I have on screen. The place image is stored in parse backend, in my attachment it is the top left image. I am trying to retrieve this and display it within the top left image.

Next to each NSLog I have the code for the model object it is building i.e. 'Di2zPyCmn8'. That's one model object id.

From my logging you can see that the cell returns before everything is complete. Which makes sense as the block is asynchronous.

Can anyone lend some assistance so I can build the tableviews correctly?

The misbehaviour is when I do not have an image in the backend in Parse for an object. The tableview cell image (top left) should be blank. Sometimes though, random image's from other backend objects can be found there.

I believe this is to do with the flow and the early returning of the cell.

When I have an image in the backend, that image displayed in the place image view (top left) as expected.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    BIDActiveDealCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[BIDActiveDealCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //get model object from array and use it's properties to populate the fields from CustomCell.h
    if ([self.activeDealModelArray count] == 0) {
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = @"Array count is 0";

    }else{
BIDActiveDealModel *dealActiveModel = [[BIDActiveDealModel alloc]init];
        dealActiveModel = self.activeDealModelArray[indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"cellforRow - start of else : %@", dealActiveModel.placeObjectId);
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = dealActiveModel.dealTitleModel;//Puts title field. Called description as too lazy to go back and change
    cell.dealPlaceNameLabel.text = dealActiveModel.placeDescription;
    //cell.dealPlaceImageView.image = dealActiveModel.placeImage;
    cell.dealImageView.image = dealActiveModel.dealImageModel;//Sets deal image
    cell.dealDescriptionLabel.text = dealActiveModel.dealDescriptionModel;
    NSLog(@"cellforRow - end of else : %@", dealActiveModel.placeObjectId);

    //Use placeObjectID (foreign key) to get that place from linkedBusinessParseClass. Then get image for that class.
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"linkedBusinessParseClass"];
    NSLog(@"cellforRow - after pfQuery : %@", dealActiveModel.placeObjectId);
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:dealActiveModel.placeObjectId block:^(PFObject *placeImageObject, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"cellforRow - start geObjectInBackground : %@", dealActiveModel.placeObjectId);
        if (!error) {
            PFFile *imageFile = [placeImageObject objectForKey:@"image"];
            [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"cellforRow - start getDataInBackground (Image) : %@", dealActiveModel.placeObjectId);
                if (!error) {
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    cell.dealPlaceImageView.image = image;
                }
                NSLog(@"cellforRow - end getDataInBackground (Image) : %@", dealActiveModel.placeObjectId);
            }];
        }
        NSLog(@"cellforRow - end geObjectInBackground : %@", dealActiveModel.placeObjectId);
    }];//end of query
}//end of else that checks array count is 0
NSLog(@"Absolute end - return cell");
return cell;


    Logging:
 cellforRow - start
 of else : Di2zPyCmn8
 cellforRow - end of else : Di2zPyCmn8
 cellforRow - after pfQuery : Di2zPyCmn8
 Absolute end - return cell
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common error. You can find a lot on SO regarding this issue when you try harder to find relevant posts.

Basically, your completion block *captures* the reference to the *cell object*. However, when the completion block eventually gets executed, the cell has been reused in the meantime. So accessing it and possibly assigning an image to a cell's view element is futile (at least), since the cell isn't the cell anymore that it was as the block captured the cell.

What you should instead capture along with the block is the *indexPath*, and then within the block *retrieve* the cell for this indexPath by sending the table view the message `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in order to obtain the correct cell *when* it's required:

**In the completion block:**

So, instead of:

```
cell.dealPlaceImageView.image = image;
```

use

```
BIDActiveDealCell* theCell = (BIDActiveDealCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
theCell.dealPlaceImageView.image = image;
```

**Note:** 
If the cell `theCell` isn't visible anymore, the table view returns `nil` - and nothing bad happens (although, there are a few other issues in your code, and this won't fix them).

#### Edit: Possible improvements/issues:

- Don't invoke messages to UIKit objects on a secondary thread - only main thread
- Avoid starting requests when there is one pending with the same URL
- Utilize an image cache (although, the system will do this to some extend)
- Use a placeholder for objects (images) which get eventually set

Comment: Thank you very detailed answer. Where you have given the line of code, I am not to sure what you mean. Where would that go? I have posted my full method so you can see. I am using a custom tableview cell. Please let me know your thoughts one you get to see the full method. Thanks!

Comment: It is clear. But it does not work. I am using a custom tableview cell. I replace UITableViewCell with my BIDActiveDealCell. Then I get a yellow warning - 'incompatible pointer types initialising BIDAciveDealCell with an expression of type UITableViewCell.' Any thoughts? I then changed it to indexPath.row and that didn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks. But the cells where the image should be blank i.e. has no image in the backend is showing images. This hasn't worked. You said that this is a common issue. What should I be searching? Can you see my problem, when you look at the logs, the return cell happens early.

Comment: I already answered this in **Possible improvements/issues:** "Use a placeholder for objects which get eventually set". More precisely, you need to set ALL properties of the cell *immediately*. If you don't have an image *yet* - use a placeholder. The placeholder image will be replaced with the actual image *later* when the completion block gets executed.  The placeholder also "overrides" the previous stale image from the reused cell ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41366/discussion-between-anthony-and-couchdeveloper)

Comment: In the discussion, it turned out that a reused cell contains stale images. With a placeholder image which will be set immediately after a reused cell has been obtained, this can be fixed (aka - clear the cell before it get's displayed!)